Is there a way, how to display and use (lookup) data from Dataverse table in SharePoint online (list)?
We are looking for a solution that will display data from a Dataverse table in SharePoint list, somehow synchronized, where list should maintain its IDs, should not be rewritten every time new data comes.
Internet is full of PA connection tips, which, unfortunately, heads into separate list. Yes, we can "look up" for values in there, however we are afraid of duplicates, rewriten rows or missing rows when something in source is deleted.
Thank you for any ideas!
